# ASUS ROG G750JS, Ubuntu 14.04, Wifi doesn't connect with modprobe wl

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom, asus

I have an [ASUS ROG G750JS](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS_ROG_G750JS/) machine, in which I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I had two problems with the installation:

1. The system froze when I asked it to reboot or shutdown. I solved it by adding the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` to the `/etc/default/grub` file.
2. It didn't detect wifi networks. I managed to make it detect my home's network by following the most upvoted answer in this question: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

However, the connection is very, very slow. Not knowing how to solve this problem, I decided to try to untoggle the wifi with `modprobe -r wl` and toggle it again with `modprobe wl`. But when I do it, it never connects again, and keeps asking for the network's password until it times out.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

#### Edit

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`, as requested:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac     
Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2123]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: @chili555 I have edited the question as per your request

Comment: Have you tried a Fedora Live Disk? As a lark I decided to search for your laptop's model number plus linux and wireless keywoards and then read this page: http://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-36021.html?s=8bcfb1f50af558f7293ce5eca589bd99

Comment: As per askubuntu's recommendation that I explain why I didn't explicitly award the bounty, I didn't feel like any of the two answers reflect first hand experience with the problem and it's solution. I upvoted them though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on further inspection, this appears to be a known bug and there appears to be a work-around available. I absolutely have not tried this.

WORKAROUND: 6_30_223_95 driver in http://people.canonical.com/~ypwong/drivers/broadcom/ , install an old version: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3 (found at http://gaspuu.blogspot.no/2014/05/dell-precision-m4800-with-ubuntu-linux.html), or simply replace the wifi module with another one with better driver support (if laptop has no whitelist for modules).

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173761

Answer (score 1):

Verify that Hardware Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS, especially the virtual MMU thing.

Otherwise 32bit drivers and its host libs are all not going to work.